# Error after transfering Laravel files to production

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I just moved my project to new server and after that I'm getting this message:

`Whoops, looks like something went wrong.`

I've changed permissions to "storage" folder and sub-folders... to 777 and nothing changed...
I wanted to see the logs... but even with 777 permissions there is no log file... :/

I also tried to get more details from the error by setting debug mode to true... but it changes nothing... :/

What needs to be done after moving files to server? Do i need to change some config to make it work?

I did the same with clean installation of Laravel 4.2 and i got the same problem... :/

**UPDATE:**

Actions made after installing new laravel 4.2 instance:

1. check i its working ("You have arrived.") so it's working.
2. create "app/config/production/app.php" (with debug => true)
3. transfer all files through ftp
4. change permissions to 777 for storage dir
5. check if its working: ("Whoops, looks like something went wrong.") its not... :/

page is here...
http://dev.slashlab.pl/lara-test/public/
(if this can help with anything... :/)

Comment: Go to your `app\config\app.php` and set `debug => true`. See what the actually error is

Comment: " I also tried to get more details from the error by setting debug mode to true... but it changes nothing... :/"

Comment: Are you sure you changed the right app and debug setting? If it was set to `true` - then you would get the full error message. The other option is check your error logs under storage and see if the error is there

Comment: Have You read my post? ;)

I've changed permisions to storage dir... but there is no log file (in "app/storage/logs/"

in clean laravel install debug is set to true... (in: app/config/app.php) so i have it in debug mode... (unless there is other place to change this setting?)

Comment: Did you specify your environment? Do you have app/config/production/app.php ?

Comment: Yes, i have (app/config/production/app.php) with nothing more than:
<?php
return array('debug' => true);

Comment: Check if your hosting has PHP 5.4 (or higher).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... after a long struggle... I found a solution... ;)

The problem was that on remote host i had `magic_quotes_gpc` turned **`on`**

Everything started to work flawlessly after turning it off. (same for laravel 4.2 and 5.0).

Thanks to all that helped, because every little answer pushed me few steps forward. :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this doesn't sounds too bananas -- but are you sure you're uploading and working in the right folder?  If you've both changed the permissions on your files, and edited the debug configuration in all your `app.php` files to no effect, one possibility is you're editing the wrong files.

Comment: yeah... i was checking everything... but i have only one folder "lara-test" on my hosting... its my first laravel deployment so i dont know if there is sth more...?

Answer (score 0):

There are (mostly) 2/3 places, where your configuration could be. `app/config/app.php` , `app/config/local/app.php` and `app/config/production/app.php`. If you set debug to true in this 2/3 places and then upload them, it is not possible to have this error page. After upload, try to download it to your computer and check the file (is it correct).

Comment: Its wierd... because i can delete folders app/config and app/start and nothing changes... 
But when i delete folder bootstrap/ then i get fatal errors...

So i think that something must be wrong before app/... folder?

Comment: Can you show us your `start.php` and `paths.php` file from bootstrap?

Comment: Of course... but it's a clean install... :/

start.php: [link](http://pastebin.com/cJaVRscc)
paths.php: [link](http://pastebin.com/xC7Lthpk)

Comment: Maybe my hosting is lacking something? But the doc's are saying only about "PHP >= 5.4" and "MCrypt PHP Extension".. and i think that all is correct: http://pastebin.com/D0cYBH7j

Comment: I found out that this message is from this file: lara-test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Exception/resources/plain.html

Does it make any sense?

Comment: In `start.php` configure your environment. Docs - http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration#environment-configuration Add there `'production' => array('yourDomain')` If this won't help we will go deeper :P

Comment: by 'yourDomain' You mean 'your-machine-name' as in docs? or ('dev.slashlab.pl') in my example?
machine name in my case would be: s79.linuxpl.com

Comment: Ok... it's done... i added also "var_dump($app->environment());"

right below... so it now shows (the same error) and info about environment: http://dev.slashlab.pl/lara-test/public/

Comment: I've tried to var dump sth from config/app.php, config/production/app.php and config/local.php but nothing shows up... even if i delete entirely "app" directory... nothing changes... o.O

Comment: i was traversing the files to find out where sth is wrong...

And i'm in file:
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php 

and ther is sth like this on line 165:
$config = $app['config']['app'];

date_default_timezone_set($config['timezone']);


But there $app is an object... and this new $config variable is an empty array... i think it fails here... :/

Comment: Go to `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Config\Repository.php` and change `offsetGet` function to this: 
`public function offsetGet($key)
{
 $this->get($key);
 var_dump($this);
}`

After that you should see information like:
`protected 'defaultPath' =>`
`protected 'environment' =>`
and afther that - `'*::app' =>`
and.. information about your config

Comment: i did what You said... http://dev.slashlab.pl/lara-test/public/
 its an empty array... ["*::app"]=> array(0) {}